# Does this Russian Republican/Civil War era badge or emblem have any historical significance?

Tags: military, identification, russia, russian-civil-war

I have been researching items from a box with some family heirlooms, and have just 3 items unaccounted for: two metal pins, and a felt badge with the colors of the Russian Republic. This was from a Russian family that sided with the Whites during the Russian Civil War and fled via the Russian Far East, and then China and Japan. I'm hopeful for any leads on whether this felt emblem and ribbon have any known historical significance.

[image]

Comment: The first badge bears a resemblance to the insignia of a WW1 Russian Imperial cannoneer (artillerist) - see the shoulder boards [here](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:1910-ab46-lpuniform.png)

Comment: great thanks to @SPavel for the helpful lead! Wikipedia appears to corroborate that the cannons may be pins that originally attached to epaulets from certain artillery ranks starting with Подпрапорщик and extending up to Полковник (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranks_and_insignia_of_the_Imperial_Russian_Armed_Forces#1884-1917).

Comment: (sorry-- shoulder straps, not epaulettes, according to the wikipedia page). There is also a complete list of Russian artillery brigades as of 1914 here with their respective stations: http://marksrussianmilitaryhistory.info/RUSS1914.html#ARTILLERY, although no further details.